# How to debug Xna 4.0 games on PC

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am very new to Xna 4.0 game development on Windows and finding it hard to debug in VS 2010. I really want to see my variable values while I am running the game. Is there any way you can debug? I see [this](https://cid-43eb71b104a2d711.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/XNA%20Game%20Studio%203.1/DebugPipelineCmd.msi) as a debugging add-in. However, I am not sure If that would work with VS 2010. Is there any other add-in or any workaround? I am working on Windows 7. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just draw the variables you want to see on the screen. Check out this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447673(XNAGameStudio.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with XNA. You can't see any variable values in VS2010 while the application is running. How would VS know, what variables to display?

For debugging purposes you can use Debug.Writeline in your code to write the value of the variable to the Console while running. That way you can track values of variables of your choice.

Comment: I agree setting up a special Debug  function for this purpose is more efficient in so many ways. Excellent answer!